# Speeding up ImageData[image,"Byte"]

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

For my image analysis I need the Byte values of many sequential 8bit PNG images.

To obtain the `Byte` data I use:

```
imageData = Flatten@ImageData[image, "Byte"]; // RepeatedTiming
{0.037, Null}
```

Here is the example image (4 Mega-Pixel) that I used:

http://goo.gl/vgKstF

Is there a way to improve the speed of this calculation, e.g. by compiling or some other approach?

Comment: You could use `Import[..., "Data"]` to import the image as a packed integer array instead of an Image. That would get rid of the `ImageData` call and the conversion to/from floating point. But `Flatten` still takes a few milliseconds. Not sure if you can improve that...

Comment: `Flatten@ImageData[Import["F:\\image.png", "PNG"], 
     "Byte"]; // RepeatedTiming`gives between 0.091 sec and 0.1 sec. In average your code `Flatten@Import["F:\\image.png", "Data"]; // RepeatedTiming` is at my computer 1 to 5 msec faster. Hmmm, what to do?

Comment: Call libpng using LibraryLink? I doubt you can improve the performance of `Import` and `Flatten` unless you rewrite most of the functionality...